# How to write & read a txt file inside a temporary directory?

Tags: python, temporary-files

I want to have a temporary directory and inside a txt file that will be removed once the temp directory is closed. But when I try to write a txt file (created inside a temporary directory), the txt file is not written, with no content in it.

**EXAMPLE:**

```py
import tempfile

message = 'this is my message'

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir='../', prefix='temp_') as td:
    td = td.replace(chr(92), '/')
    with open(f'{td}/filename.txt', 'w+') as temporary_file:
        temporary_file.write(message)
        temporary_file.read()
        # do some stuff here
# the temporary directory was closed, removing the txt file.
```

Comment: You look to be missing a `temporary_file.seek(0)` between your write and read.

Comment: it's certainly like that, I wasn't using it